# $10$ Balls: Selecting Certain Numbers of Each Color

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There exist piles of balls of the colors red, blue, and green. Each pile contains at least $10$ balls. How many ways can $10$ balls be selected if at least one red ball, at least two blue balls, and at least three green balls must be selected?

Comment: Does the order the colors are selected matter, or just the final quantities?

Comment: Final quantities.

Comment: How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let $r,b$, and $g$ be the numbers of red, blue, and green balls selected, respectively. You’re looking for the number of solutions to $r+b+g=10$ in integers $r,b,g$ such that $r\ge 1$, $b\ge 2$, and $g\ge 3$. You might as well just pick one red, two blue, and three green balls to begin with; then you just have to pick $r'$ red, $b'$ blue, and $g'$ green balls such that $r'+b'+g'=4$, and $r',b'$, and $g'$ are non-negative integers. This is a standard [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) problem; at the link you’ll find both a formula and a fairly decent explanation of the reasoning justifying that formula.